# Find $g''(\pi/3)$ if given two definite integrals

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find $g''(\pi/3)$ if
>   $$f(x) = \int_0^{\cos x} \sqrt{1+t^2} \, dt \text{ and } g(y) = \int_e^y f(x) \, dx.$$

So I realize I need to find the second derivative of $g(y)$, and the first step is to use the first theorem  of calculus. Thus, by applying the first derivative, I  obtain $$g'(y) = \sqrt{1 + \cos^2(x)}.$$
I am lost on the next step.
I would like some clarification please.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** It seems that you are skipping steps and that you forgot to apply Chain Rule. Let $u = \cos y$. Then note that:
\begin{align*}
g'(y) &= \frac{d}{dy} \int_e^y f(x) \, dx = f(y) \\
g''(y) &= f'(y) = \frac{d}{dy} \int_0^u \sqrt{1 + t^2} \, dt = \sqrt{1 + u^2} \cdot \frac{du}{dy} = \cdots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

(Yes, I know I abuse some notation.) We have
$$g^{\prime}(y) = f(y)$$
(do you see why?)
so
$$g^{\prime\prime}(y) = f^{\prime}(y)$$
Now 
$$f(x) = H[\cos(x)]-H(0)$$
(using the integral equation) where $H$ is an antiderivative of $\sqrt{1+t^2}$, so, by applying the chain rule, we have
$$f^{\prime}(x) = H^{\prime}[\cos(x)](-\sin(x)) - 0$$
since $H(0)$ is constant. But $H^{\prime} = \sqrt{1+t^2}$, so 
$$f^{\prime}(x) = \sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)} \cdot (-\sin(x))$$
and hence
$$g^{\prime\prime}(y)=f^{\prime}(y)=-\sin(y)\sqrt{1+\cos^{2}(y)}$$
and now for $g^{\prime\prime}(\pi/3)$, set $y = \pi/3$ and you are done.

Comment: May I ask, i am rusty and refreshing my mind on calculus, but when do I have to use the chain rule ? Thank you!

Comment: @user3676224 Because you have a function of a function. Recall the chain rule: derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $f^{\prime}(g(x)) \cdot g^{\prime}(x)$. Analogously, we have $H[\cos(x)]$ here.

Answer (score 1):

From the fundamental theorem you get
$$g'(y)=f(y).$$
So 
$$g''(y)=\frac{d}{dy}\int_{0}^{\cos y}\sqrt{1+t^2} \, dt=\sqrt{1+\cos^2 y} \, \cdot (-\sin y).$$

Comment: Hi @Anurag, for typing derivatives `g'` looks better than `g^{'}`.